# Why adding the two proper fractions give 1?

Tags: binomial-theorem

I came across this example question while studying Binomial Theorem. Here it is :–

> **If $n$ is any positive integer, show that the integral part of $(3+√7)^n$ is an odd number.**
>
> Suppose $I$ to denote the integral and $f$ the fractional part of $(3+√7)^n$.
>
> Then,
>
> $I+f=3^n+C_13^{n-1}√7+C_23^{n-2}7+C_33^{n-3}(√7)^3+........          —(1)$
>
> Now $3-√7$ is positive and less than $1$, therefore $(3-√7)^n$ is a proper fraction; denote it by $f'$;
>
> $f'=3^n-C_13^{n-1}√7+C_23^{n-2}7-C_33^{n-3}(√7)^3+........                 —(2)$
>
> Add together (1) and (2); the irrational terms disappear, and we have
>
> $I+f+f'=2(3^n+C_23^{n-2}7+....)=$ an even integer.
>
> But since $f$ and $f'$ are proper fractions their sum must be 1;
>
> I= an odd integer

The only thing I am not able to understand here is-

**Why adding any 2 proper fraction gives 1?**

**Can anyone provide a convincing proof of this?**

Comment: "But since and are proper fractions" looks like something is missing. Did you mean "since $f$ and $f'$ are proper fractions"?

Comment: It's not that adding **any** $2$ proper fractions gives $1$; however, if the sum of two proper fractions **is an integer**, then that integer must be $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
I+f+f'= 2k\ ,\ \text{or}\\
f+f'=2k-I
$$
where $\ k\ $ and $\ I\ $ are integers, and $\ f, f'\ $ are proper fractions—that is $\ 0<f,f'< 1\ $. Thus, $\ 0<f+f'<2\ $.  Therefore, since $\ f+f'\ $ is an integer, and $1$ is the *only* integer in the interval $\ (0,2)\ $, it follows that $\ f+f'=1\ $.